# Intercepting packets with bash

Tags: bash, networking, shell-script

I'm wondering if it's possible to detect a packet that comes from certain IP and port(suppose IP 1.1.1.1 and port 80) and has some specific information on it (suppose "<h1>Web Authentication</h1>), drop it before the client (suppose Firefox) receives it and execute certain commands (or another bash script) after this. If possible, ONLY WITH BASH, without any weird command that's not installed by default on linux nor programs from repositories.

Comment: Only with bash? No. But why do you want to forbid the normal tool to do this (which is not a “weird command that's not installed by default on linux”)? (That would be `iptables`, by the way.)

Comment: You can simply Setup Proxy Server, which help you create rule based on headers filtering and you can also run script called external parser.

Comment: According to said Gilles, you can use `iptables-save`, `iptabes-restore` and `iptables -F `, So you can have bash script.

Comment: I don't think iptables could detect authenticated headers. isn't it?

Comment: If it's SSL encrypted, no, iptables cannot inspect it. This shouldn't be done on the packet layer anyway. TCP is a stream, meaning the contents could be split up among multiple packets. A proxy is the right way to do this.

Comment: That's it, @Patrick is right!
Any ideas about how to implement a proxy in bash? Could it be possible?

Comment: There's not really such thing as "just bash". You're going to use external sommands such as "awk", and I guess you could plug something together with inetd and nc, but you really, really do not want to do this. Your question shows a huge underappreciation of how far apart "bash" and "packet" and "client" actually are, conceptually.

Comment: Even if it's not HTTPS, there is the added little problem that `gzip` is used a lot to compress HTML. You have to assemble HTTP GET bodies and decompress. What is the plan for inserting Bash between Firefox and the Webserver? A good architecture for intercepting web requests between a browser and server is to have an HTTP proxy in between. I don't think it's feasible to write a HTTP proxy in Bash. If Bash had some sort of socket support, it might be doable.

Comment: @NicoRodsevich Are you sure you want to do this in pure Bash? There's a good chance that's impossible. If your goal is simplicity and portability then you might consider rewording your question to restrict solutions to POSIX environments.